# Weak convergence in $L^{p,\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-lp-spaces

Are the weak $L^p$ spaces, namely $L^{p,\infty}$, weak or weak-$\star$ compact?

Specifically I would like to know if we have a sequence $(u_\varepsilon)_{\varepsilon>0}$ which is bounded in $L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ independently on $\varepsilon > 0$, do we know if there exists an element $u\in L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $u_\varepsilon \rightharpoonup u$ weak or weak-$\star$ in $L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ maybe up to a subsequence?

Comment: What is $L^{p,\infty}$? Is the same with the casual $L^p$?

Comment: @dem0nakos no, these are larger spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space, but I am concerned with weak $L^p$, which are particular cases of those Loretz spaces (you can find a review in the link)

Comment: I'll check the definitions. But for the casual $L_p$ spaces for $1<p<\infty$ what you are asking is true. This is a consequence of their reflexivity for $1<p<\infty$. For $p=1$ it is not true. I.e. you can have a bounded sequence in $L_1$ that has no weakly convergent subsequence.